# Reading file from web

Tags: java

So what I am trying to achieve is reading the contents of a .txt file from a url:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
File f = new File ("www.website.com/filename.txt");

if (f.exists()) {
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String line = "";

    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);    
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Even though I have content in the .txt file (only one line), when I print the line nothing shows up. Is reading a file from a URL or from your hard drive different, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class is for files on a "normal" file system (usually local, but potentially networked) - not URLs. Basically it's for the sort of file you can use (e.g. read or edit) directly on a command line, with no HTTP involved<sup>1</sup>.

That's what the [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class is for. So you can either use that (with [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)) or use a dedicated HTTP 3rd party library, such as the [Apache `HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) library.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm sure there are some shells which allow the use of URLs as if they were local filenames, but I'm talking about a more traditional approach.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll use the URL class to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried own my own and this worked...

```
  URL urlObj=new URL("http://www.example.com/index.html");   //This can be any website' index.html or an available file
                                                            //we basically get HTML page/file
    Scanner fGetter=new Scanner(urlObj.openStream());

    while(fGetter.hasNext()){

       System.out.println(""+fGetter.nextLine());

    }
```

And I think "example.com" can be used without any legal issues :)

Comment: Obviously I'm not checking for errors/exceptions as its just an example

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know but I don't think you can read a file from a URL like that. You need to send a HTTP GET request to that url to read the information in.

See object `HttpURLConnection`.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html